# Advantage from static routing to dynamic routing on Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-routes

I can see that `MaterialApp` app can receive routes.

## 1. Static routing

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      routes: {
        '/page1': (context) => Page1(title: "Main page"),
...
```

And show them from the widgets like:

```dart
myKey.currentState.pushNamed("/page1");
```

There are other parameters like `onGenerateRoute` and `initialRoute` which confuse me more.

## 2. Dynamic Pages

```dart
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
  );
}
```

## Question

Im wondering what is the implication of this parameters and letting this "responsibility" to the `MaterialApp`, and why we should do it, maybe something related to memory management or how the `Widget` lifecycle works, or what?

What are the differences between 1. and 2.?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The answer lies more in your architecture than anything.

**1. Static Routing** is the better of the two in terms of managing a projects complexity. Routes are clearly defined for multiple developers to understand, and the navigation code is much easier, `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('your-route');` vs

```
Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondRoute()),
 );
```

**2. Dynamic Pages** is commonly in tutorials and such to reduce boilerplate code. It is merely a shortcut to navigate. The downside of this is it becomes hard to manage routes, and so should be limited to short tutorials.

**3. Generated Routes** There is a third option though, that in my opinion is the best of the two, and that is a Generated Routes. This is the cleanest and easiest to mantain structure. There is a great tutorial [here](https://www.filledstacks.com/snippet/clean-navigation-in-flutter-using-generated-routes/) about it. Here is the rundown:

1. Declare Routes:

```
class RoutePaths {
  static const Start = '/';
  static const SecondScreen = 'second'
}
```

2. Declare your router:

```
class Router {
  static Route<dynamic> generateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case RoutePaths.Start:
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => YourFirstScreenWidget());

      case RoutePaths.SecondScreen:
        // you can do things like pass arguments to screens
        final event = settings.arguments as Event;
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => YourSecondScreenWidget(event: event));

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (_) => Scaffold(
                  body: Center(
                    child: Text('No route defined for ${settings.name}'),
                  ),
                ));
    }
  }
}
```

3. Declare it in main.dart

```
initialRoute: RoutePaths.Start,
onGenerateRoute: Router.generateRoute,
```

4. Navigate

```
// arguments: event is an optional parameter to send to secondScreen
Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RoutePaths.SecondScreen, arguments: event);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Completely falls over with views like Drawer and tabview though.